# how to show text right align

Tags: android

this is my code for text view which space from left but i want to left allign text how i do that? how much name is long its align from right

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblUnabletoProceed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dip"
        android:textColor="#FFCC00"                
        android:text="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use `android:gravity="right"` or   `android:layout_gravity="right"` in linearLayout and its better to use Relativelayout. In relative Layout use  `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`, for a margin  `android:layout_marginRight="5dp"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblUnabletoProceed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dip"
        android:textColor="#FFCC00"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:text="" />
```

Comment: but its show no space from right i want atleast show 2 charector space from right how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Comment: thnx its work but its no leave anyspace from right its look bad how i change this code so is show atleace 2 charecter space from right??

Answer (score 0):

Use for align

`android:gravity="right"`

and use for margin/padding

`android:paddingRight=16dip`

this will give you alignment to the right and spacing.